# protobuf-net decorators for methods and for multiple subClasses of a main class

Tags: protobuf-net

in OOP, how do we decorate methods ... and multiple subclasses?

such as:

```
[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(L1Token))]
[ProtoInclude(2, typeof(L2Token))]
public class Token { ... }

[ProtoContract]
public class L1Token : Token { ... }

[ProtoContract]
public class L2Token : Token { 
    ... 

    [OperationContract ?????]
    public override string ToString()
    { ... }
}
```

Also, what's the use of the other decorators, such as:

[ProtoBehavior]

[OperationContract]

or 
[DataMember(Order = 1)]  ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

subclasses: you've already shown how to do that - what you have *is it*; if I'm misunderstanding that part of the question, please clarify and I'll try to help more

methods: you don't; protobuf-net isn't very interested in methods - it is a *data* serializer, not an RPC stack; if you want an RPC stack: consider protobuf-net.Grpc, which brings the WCF flavor to gRPC using protobuf-net and the underlying Google/Microsoft gRPC stacks; [here's the getting started docs](https://protobuf-net.github.io/protobuf-net.Grpc/gettingstarted); this also discusses `[OperationContract]` in that context.

`[ProtoBehavior]` is directly related to WCF; are you using WCF? in all honesty, most people aren't; again, if you're looking for protobuf-based RPC, I'd rather point you in the direction of protobuf-net.Grpc

As for `[DataMember(Order = 1)]`: protobuf-net needs numeric tokens to resolve fields; there are multiple ways it will accept them, to allow wider compatibility; the most typical (and most powerful, as it allows finer control) is to use the library's own attributes:

```cs
[ProtoContract]
public class Foo {
    [ProtoMember(1)] public int X {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(2)] public string Y {get;set;}
    [ProtoMember(3)] public long Z {get;set;}
}
```

However, the above will be 100% compatible with the same intent expressed via alternative attributes:

```cs
[DataContract]
public class Foo {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)] public int X {get;set;}
    [DataMember(Order = 2)] public string Y {get;set;}
    [DataMember(Order = 3)] public long Z {get;set;}
}
```

(and also `[XmlType]/[XmlElement(...)]`)

It *prefers* the library specific attributes, and if it fins those: they win.